# Signature Arguments in Prototype as Function SIgnature or Function Pointer, Is there a Difference?

Tags: c, function, pointers, prototype, signature

**Here is the source code for the supporting function in main:**

```
static char * string(int i) {
    char * temp = malloc (sizeof *temp * strlen("1 My function"));
    temp = strcpy(temp, "0 My function");
    if (i) {
        temp[0]+=i;
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

---

**Here are the signatures within a signature, some pointers, some signatures:**

```
static char * signaturesA (int i, char * func(int j)){
    return (*(&func))(i);
}

static char * signaturesB (int i, char (* func)(int j)){
    return func(i);
}

static char * sigptrsA (int i, char * func(int j)){
    return func(i);
}

static char * sigptrsB (int i, char * (*func)(int j)){
    return (*func)(i);
}
    
int main(void) {
    puts(signaturesA(1, string));
    puts(signaturesB(2, string));
    puts(sigptrsA(3, string));
    puts(sigptrsB(4, string));

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the source **output directly from gdb debugging** at the terminal for the program above being run with the selected objects and pointers, **bold emphasizes the output** of the function to terminal:

---

Breakpoint 1, signaturesA (i=1, func=0x555555555440 ) at keyboard.c:90

90      return (*(&func))(i);

1: func = (char *(*)(int)) 0x555555555440

2: *func = {char *(int)} 0x555555555440

11: &func = (char *(**)(int)) 0x7fffffffddf0

**1 My function**

Breakpoint 2, signaturesB (i=2, func=0x555555555440 ) at keyboard.c:93

93      return func(i);

3: func = (char *(*)(int)) 0x555555555440

4: *func = {char *(int)} 0x555555555440

10: &func = (char *(**)(int)) 0x7fffffffddf0

**2 My function**

Breakpoint 3, sigptrsA (i=3, func=0x555555555440 ) at keyboard.c:96

96      return func(i);

5: func = (char *(*)(int)) 0x555555555440

6: *func = {char *(int)} 0x555555555440

12: &func = (char *(**)(int)) 0x7fffffffddf0

**3 My function**

Breakpoint 4, sigptrsB (i=4, func=0x555555555440 ) at keyboard.c:99

99      return (*func)(i);

7: func = (char *(*)(int)) 0x555555555440

8: *func = {char *(int)} 0x555555555440

9: &func = (char *(**)(int)) 0x7fffffffddf0

**4 My function**

---

**Questions(3):**

---

1. What is the application of the three different styles of function addressing distinguished? One groups with **braces**, the other **parenthesis**:

   7: func = (char * (*)(int)) 0x555555555440

   8: *func = {char * (int)} 0x555555555440

   9: &func = (char * (**)(int)) 0x7fffffffddf0

---

2. What is the application of the two **different parameter styles** within a function as distinguished?

   ```
    static char * sigptrsA (int i, char *   func (int j));

    static char * sigptrsB (int i, char * (*func)(int j));
   ```

---

3. Anything else to consider regarding this question?

---

Comment: `malloc (sizeof *temp * strlen("1 My function"));` does not allocate enough space for the subsequent `strcpy`.  You need space for the terminating nul character.

Answer (score 1):

```
static char * sigptrsA (int i, char *   func (int j));
static char * sigptrsB (int i, char * (*func)(int j));
```

The function `sigptrsA()` takes a 'function that returns a `char *`', but that is automatically converted to 'pointer to a function that returns a `char *`.  This is defined in C11 [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p8):

> A declaration of a parameter as "function returning type" shall be adjusted to "pointer to function returning type", as in [§6.3.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4).

The function `sigptrsB()` takes a 'pointer to a function that returns a `char *`' it explicitly uses the function pointer notation.

As a consequence, the two functions take equivalent arguments.

Comment: That was a type which I corrected, thank you! Question 2 code is accurate. I think that the reference automatically removes a layer of indirection from whatever is placed in that argument, either a pointer to a function or an actual function call returning a function of the same signature as the parameter specifies which would allow a identifier to be called that uses the same group of arguments twice, once on the call at the initialization of the call and once on the return of that call from another(or same func) which would allow creative treatment of input objects/pointers to overland.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to tell when something is a typo and when it is not.  I've adjusted my answer — the function signatures are equivalent.  I learned C when you had to invoke a function via a pointer to a function using `(*ptr_to_func)(arg, list)` and still usually write function calls via a pointer to a function that way.  That follows the 'declaration mimics usage' rule.  The C90 standard added the equivalent `ptr_to_func(arg, list)` notation. Many people only use that notation.