# Why is declaring a function parameter instead of function pointer parameter allowed?

Tags: c, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I don't really know what I expect as an answer to this but being able to declare function parameter while not being able to declare variable inside a function the same way makes me uneasy.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void why_is_this_allowed()) {
    why_is_this_allowed();
}

void func2(void (*this_makes_more_sense)()) {
    this_makes_more_sense();
}

void print() {
    printf("I am stuff\n");
}

int main()
{
    void and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed() = print;
    
    func(print);
    func2(print);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: previously answered:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75443662/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like how arrays as parameters are adjusted to be pointers, functions as parameters are adjusted to function pointers.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p8 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf):

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
> adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

That means that this:

```
void func(void why_is_this_allowed()) {
    why_is_this_allowed();
}
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
void func(void (*why_is_this_allowed)()) {
    why_is_this_allowed();
}
```

In contrast, this doesn't work:

```
void and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed() = print;
```

Because no such adjustment happens, so `and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed` is taken to be a function declaration, and such a declaration is not an lvalue and therefore can't be assigned to.

Comment: But what is the rationale about allowing this as a parameter but not doing the same for a variable declared that way ?

Comment: @nescius Because it doesn't make sense to declare a function in a parameter list, while it does make sense to declare a function in a local scope.

Comment: And why does there need to be a rationale anyway, @nescius, other than "it seemed like a good idea at the time"?

Comment: @nescius You're right that it's an obvious flaw in the language.  There were probably inconsistent existing implementations, so the ANSI folks decided to just allow everything, and have the compiler "fix it" if it wasn't what it should be.  No well-designed language would silently accept both without error or warning.  Just be glad that `&arr` isn't treated as `arr` as it used to be with some compilers, but now correctly gives a pointer to the array.  At least with functions, there's no useful alternative interpretation, so it seems harmless.

Comment: @nescius Actually, I think historically there was always some inconsistency, even in K&R.  If you had a function `func`, and a function pointer `fp`, then you would do `fp = func;` to set the pointer, but `(*fp)(...)` to call the function pointed to by `fp`.  So the indirection was inconsistent.  That might be a large part of the reason it's the way it is now:  They wanted to eliminate some of the inconsistency, but not break existing code.  So now both `fp = &func;` and `fp(...)` are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler adjusts function parameters having function types to pointers to function types. So these two function declarations

```
void func(void why_is_this_allowed());

void func(void (*why_is_this_allowed)());
```

declare the same one function.

On the other hand, a function designator used in an expression is implicitly converted to pointer to the function type.

Consider for example this code snippet

```
void f( void )
{
}

//...

void ( *pf )( void ) = f;
```

In this code snippet the function designator `f` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to the function.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
> operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
> is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
> returning type’’.

and (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
> adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

This line

```
void and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed() = print;
```

does not make sense because a function declaration opposite to a declaration of a pointer does not declare an object. So the  initializer for a declaration of a function specifier does not have a meaning.

It is the same as to write

```
int x;

int = x;
```

As you can see the last line is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the reason why it works like this but this is the right way to declare a function pointer and use it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void why_is_this_allowed()) {
    why_is_this_allowed();
}

void func2(void (*this_makes_more_sense)()) {
    this_makes_more_sense();
}

void print() {
    printf("I am stuff\n");
}

int main()
{
    // function pointer declaration and initialization
    void (*and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed)(void) = &print;

    func(print);
    func2(print);

    // calling the function
    and_why_is_this_NOT_allowed();
    return 0;
}
```

hope this is helpful.